# Getting Landsat 7 images scanline errors in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, landsat-7

I have used "Fix Landsat 7 Scanline Errors" tool to remove the stripes from the raster. Though the black scan lines are removed but the raster gets scratches. See 
 screen shot below.

How can I solve this or is there any other way to remove the scan lines?

[image: Landsat screenshot]

Comment: The way the filling procedure works is that usually you find another Landast 7 image of the same area and use that to fill the gaps of you image. Also, please refer to this page to choose which image should be the best for this: https://landsat.usgs.gov/which-images-will-work-best-fill-gaps. Normally you don't have perfect results, especially if your image has clouds.

Answer (score 1):

For ArcMap software there is a tool named Landsat tool which helps in removing scan line error of Landsat 7 images:

- [Landsat Toolbox for Shoreline Extraction](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=e424afd2d30a427fbb8e614f0845ae31)

Above is the link to download the Landsat toolbox which will help to remove scanline errors.